# XCode - QR Code Detection change to specific view

Tags: detection, qr-code, marker, xcode4.3

I am coding a game which should start several mini-games when scanning a specific QR-Code. 
Now the question is: how can I implement the QR-Code Marker Detection and let the view change to a specific view with the mini-game according to the marker code?

Any ideas?

View Based Application - Xcode 4.3.2 - iOS 5 - iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) or [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: thought ZXing would be for Android and Java-Bases Applications and there would be just a small part for iOS?! Is this small part enough?

Comment: There is a C++ port of much of ZXing and Objective C interfaces to the C++ code (see the iphone and objc directories). Although the 1D support is not complete, the QR code support is. (FWIW, I do a lot of the QR code support.)

Comment: Thank you. Will test it and let you know if i need help.